# How to set the logging level for the elasticsearch library differently to my own logging?

Tags: python, logging, module

How can I set the logging level for the elasticsearch library differently to my own logging? To illustrate the issue, I describe the module scenario. I have a module `lookup.py` which uses `elasticsearch` like this:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
import elasticsearch

def get_docs():
    logger.debug("search elastic")
    es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch('http://my-es-server:9200/')
    res = es.search(index='myindex', body='myquery')
    logger.debug("elastic returns %s hits" % res['hits']['total'])
    .
    .
.
```

Then in my main file I do

```
import logging
import lookup.py

logging.root.setLevel(loglevel(args))
get_docs()
.
.
.
```

I get lots of debug messages from *inside* the Elasticsearch object. How can I suppress them with some code in `lookup.py` without suppressing the debug messages in `lookup.py` itself? The `Elasticsearch` class seems to have a `logger` object; I  I tried to set it to `None`, but this didn't change anything.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The following two lines have done the trick for me to suppress excessive logging from the es library.

`es_logger = logging.getLogger('elasticsearch')
 es_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)`

Answer (score 7):

In recent (v8.5) versions of elasticsearch, the chatty POST log seems to have moved to elastic_transport:

`logging.getLogger('elastic_transport.transport').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)`

Answer (score 4):

I have been using this:

```
from elasticsearch import logger as es_logger

LOGLEVEL = 50
es_logger.setLevel(LOGLEVEL)
```

Answer (score 2):

As a supplementary answer, if you have several loggers in your project, you can do this way:

```
import elasticsearch

es_logger = elasticsearch.logger
es_logger.setLevel(elasticsearch.logging.WARNING)
```

The pros:

- You have full control and make sure that the elastic search logger won't collide with other loggers
- You may set WARNING/ERROR or DEBUG levels without remembering what number will mean

The cons:

- You are dependent on internal logger implementation of elastic search

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me. I dived into elasticsearch (8.11.1) and found the spot that logs, and pulled out the logger name. Do this:

```
es_logger = logging.getLogger("elastic_transport.transport")
es_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```